# Code to convert work hours wraps to 24 hours?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code which takes for example, 27:30 (27 hours 30 minutes) and converts it to a decimal like 27.5. I have another function that does the opposite.

```
 public class Time
    {
        public static string Hours(decimal d)
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromHours((double)(d + 0.005M)).ToString("h\\:mm");
        }

        public static decimal Hours(string s)
        {
            decimal r;
            if (decimal.TryParse(s, out r))
                return r;

            return (decimal)TimeSpan.Parse(s).TotalHours + 0.005M;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the conversion from decimal to string seems to wrap to 24 hours. If I give it 30.0 it gives me 6:00 which is wrong. It should be 30:00

What could I do to avoid the wrap?

Thanks

Comment: It's not wrapping at 24 hours, you have to look at the "Days" property as well.  For 30 hours, Days=1 and Hours=6.  That's why you are seeing "6:00".

Comment: @ConradFrix, the "h" in the TimeSpan's ToString does not show the "TotalHours".  It pulls from just the "Hours" property.

Comment: @David my mistake I was looking `Hours(string s)` instead of `Hours(decimal)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no format specifier for `TotalHours`, so you have to write whole logic by yourself:

```
public static string Hours(decimal d)
{
    var ts = TimeSpan.FromHours((double)(d + 0.005M));
    return string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", (int)ts.TotalHours, ts.Minutes);
}
```

`(int)ts.TotalHours` casting truncates minuts from number of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ToString` to get the minutes only, and calculate the hours yourself.

```
return string.Format("{0:0}:{1}", Math.Truncate(d+0.005m), TimeSpan.FromHours(d+0.005m).ToString("mm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `h` format only reports hours not counted as parts of days.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

You can either output the number of days by adding a `d` or perform the conversion in your own code if you want a non-standard behavior.